# Fetch with react typescript no data get

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fetch-api

I'm new to react with typescript and I follow a tutorial for improve at the moment I try to get some data via the fetch method from the tvmaze API but nothing happens and I don't understand why any solution?:

```
    import React , { Fragment, useEffect, useContext } from 'react'
    import Store from '../Store/Store'
    import "core-js/stable";
    import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
    
    export default function App() {
    
      const {state, dispatch} = useContext(Store)
    
      useEffect(() => {
        state.episodes.length === 0 && fetchDataAction()
      })
    
      const fetchDataAction = async () => {
        const URL = 'http://api.tvmaze.com/singlesearch/shows?q=rick-&-morty&embed=episodes'
        const data = await fetch(URL);
        const dataJSON = await data.json();
        return  dispatch({
          type: 'FETCH-DATA',
          payload: dataJSON._embedded.episodes
        })
      }
    
    
      return (
        <Fragment>
          {console.log(state)}
          <h1>Rick and Morty</h1>
          <p>Pick your favorite episode!!!</p>
          <section>
            {state.episodes.map((episode: any) => {
              return (
                <section key={episode.id}>
                  <img src={episode.image.medium} alt={`Rick and Morty ${episode.name}`} />
                  <section>
                    Season: {episode.season} Number: {episode.number}
                  </section>
                </section>
              )
            })}
          </section>
        </Fragment>
      )
    }


export default app
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your `async` fetch call in a `try` `catch` block to see if the promise of the fetch call is resolving? You can also chain a `.catch` to the end of your `fetch()` call to test this. You should also be looking at your network tab in your DevTools to see if there are any network errors when the request is made, or check if `if (response.ok)` is true and force an error if not (see: https://gomakethings.com/error-handing-when-using-the-vanilla-js-fetch-method-with-async-and-await/)

Comment: i get the data display if do console.log(dataJSON._embedded.episodes) but the state not fill if i do console.log(state) i get an empty array this is my issue.

Comment: Ok so it's a state update issue. Pass the `state` object in your `useEffect` dependency array so that it runs whenever the `state` object updates (look into conditionally firing effects), giving you an idea of when your store is actually updating. `useEffect` by default only runs after the component has already mounted or rendered, so as it is now, your fetch request is only running after your component has rendered. Your fetch request is also asynchronous, your component may be mounting before the fetch promise has resolved and returned any data.

Comment: It may be better to keep this state local as well and assign the response value to local state, e.g: `const [ state, setState ] = useState({})`, then `await setState(dataJSON)`. When local state is updated it causes a component rerender, so your component should render using the data assigned to it after the fetch request has completed (and not anytime before).